# Defining attributes using OOP in python

Tags: python, object, oop

I am currently using OOP in python to program a game. I have created a class with attributes and methods. I wanted to do basic movement where if the user types "go north" it will move to the north square. However it is saying i have an error and that north isn't defined. Here is my code:

```
class square():
    def __init__(self, action, square_no, north, east, south, west):
        
        self.action = action
        self.square_no = square_no
        self.north = north
        self.east = east
        self.south = south
        self.west = west

    def user_action(action):
        action = input("---").lower()

        square.movement(action, north)

    def Help():
        print("Commands are: \n Go(north/ east /south /west) \n Mine \n Craft (object) \n Look around \n Collect (blueprint)\n Fix (wing/ thruster/ engine/ battery/ fuel tank) \n Save \n Info \n You will see this symbol when you are expected to type something ---")
        square.user_action(action)

    def movement(action, north):
             
        if action == "go north":
            print(north)

        elif action == "info":
            square.Help()   
            
        else:
            print("You can't do that here.")
            square.user_action(action)


action = ""

square1 = square(action, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0)
print(square1)

square1.user_action()
```

Thanks

Comment: Your instance methods need the `self` argument for the instance itself, then you can access `self.north`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `self` in various places for the code to work as intended

```
class square():
    def __init__(self, action, square_no, north, east, south, west):
        
        self.action = action
        self.square_no = square_no
        self.north = north
        self.east = east
        self.south = south
        self.west = west

    def user_action(self):
        action = input("---").lower()

        self.movement(action)

    def Help(self):
        print("Commands are: \n Go(north/ east /south /west) \n Mine \n Craft (object) \n Look around \n Collect (blueprint)\n Fix (wing/ thruster/ engine/ battery/ fuel tank) \n Save \n Info \n You will see this symbol when you are expected to type something ---")
        self.user_action(action)

    def movement(self,action):
             
        if action == "go north":
            print(self.north)

        elif action == "info":
            square.Help()   
            
        else:
            print("You can't do that here.")
            square.user_action(action)


action = ""

square1 = square(action, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0)
print(square1)
square1.user_action()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using self.north.

```
square.movement(action, self.north)
```

You are trying to use a variable called north which isn't set. But you do have the variable north in your class which you have to acces via self.<variable_name>.

I hope it solves your problem